# How to Change Font Size of Cell in uitableview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I tried this, but it is not working.

```
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=NO;
cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize=6;
```

I need a code snippet.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 18.0 ];
cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;
```

[UIFont reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 39):

Change font size and font family.

```
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
```

change font size

```
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
```

Answer (score 13):

Another simple one:

```
cell.textLabel.font = [cell.textLabel.font fontWithSize:19];
```

this way you change only the font size mantaining all the font format.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontSize:15.0f];
```

All the best.

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:yourSize];
```

or

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:yourSize];
```

Answer (score 4):

Or if you just want to change the font size you can use

`cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];`

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 version:

```
cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
```

Warning: if you write a wrong font name, this operation will be simply ignored (it won't be used the default font with the specified size).

Answer (score 1):

simple one

```
 myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
```