# How can I change the font size of my UITableView cell title?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

How can I change the font size of my UITableView cell title in XCode?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change font size of cell in uitableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323777/how-to-change-font-size-of-cell-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you are doing this programatically, then you can set the property `cell.textLabel.font` in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Specifically, to change the size, you would write:

```
 cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

Which would resize your font to size 12.0 pts.

Comment: thanks! How can I make the text fit into the cell - because there are ... after my cell title?

Comment: Just to understand: am I correct that what you want to do is have text in the cell of a desired size, but that if the text is too big, the textLabel should be rescaled so that it fits?

Comment: indeed, like the "Adjust to Fit" option for a UITextField.

Comment: This should do the trick: `cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;` (not sure if second line is necessary!)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom UITableViewCell and assign labels using the sizes you want.