# change the font size of reveal sidebar menu from programming in swift

Tags: swift, menu, side-menu

Regarding to the following image:

[image]

How do I increase the font size?

This is the code of `BackTableVC.swift`:

```
import Foundation

class BackTableVC: UITableViewController {

    var tableArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableArray = ["event log", "my details", "research", "share", "checklists", "templates", "helpful links", "feedback"]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableArray.count;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableArray[indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

        return cell
    }
```

How do I increase the font size? Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957215/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-my-uitableview-cell-title

Comment: You can directly use this  cell.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 15.0)

Comment: Add `cell.textLabel?.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 16.0];` to your `tableView` function. You can change 16.0 to any other font size you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableArray[indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}
```

In the example above you'll be changing the font size, but not the font family, if you want to change the family as well you can use this code.

```
UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class BackTableVC: UITableViewController{
    var tableArray = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableArray = ["event log","my details","research","share","checklists","templates","helpful links","feedback"]
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableArray.count;
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableArray[indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)//set your font size replace the 25 with your font size

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: @PremPrakashBashyal please make it trusted answer with green right tick that helps to other....and please vote up the answer